# Transform a 3D numpy array to 1D based on column value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Maybe this is a very simple task, but I have a numpy.ndarray with shape (1988,3).

```python
preds = [[1 0 0]
        [0 1 0]
        [0 0 0]
        ...
        [0 1 0]
        [1 0 0]
        [0 0 1]]
```

I want to create a 1D array with shape=(1988,) that will have values corresponding to the column of my 3D array that has a value of 1.

For example,

```python
 new_preds = [0 1 NaN ... 1 0 2]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: try this ```new_preds = np.argmax(preds, axis=1)```

Comment: Do you only have exactly one 1 per row? If not can you provide an updated example?

Comment: No, sometimes there might be rows that have only zeros, because the predictions where lower than a certain threshold, so they didn't become 1.

Comment: Not sure what to do with those predictions actually, maybe the best idea would be to drop them or change them to NaN values, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html):

```
preds = [[1, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 1],
         [0, 1, 0],
         [1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1]]

new_preds = np.nonzero(preds)[1]
```

Output: `array([0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2])`

##### handling rows with no match:

```
preds = [[1, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 0],
         [1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1]]

x, y = np.nonzero(preds)

out = np.full(len(preds), np.nan)

out[x] = y
```

Output: `array([ 0.,  1., nan,  1.,  0.,  2.])`

Comment: perhaps `out = np.full(len(preds), np.nan)` instead of `empty()`/`fill()`?